# Java: Counting (and "removing") max-/minimum value of 2D array

Tags: java, arrays

I want the method to count all the maximum/minimum values in the 2D array `poängInsamling`. Each `domare` (=judge) gives a value to all `deltagare` (=members). I want to remove the `maximum/minimum` value of each `deltagare`. The code I have now only works if there are `2` or less members.

This is what I got:

```
        for (int x = 0; x < deltagare; x++) {
            for (int y = 0; y < domare; y++) {
                if (poängInsamling[y][x] == -1) {
                    poängInsamling[y][x] = 0;
                    break;
                }       
            }
        }
    return poängInsamling;
}
```

Thanks in advance, I've been trying to fix this for hours.

Edit: `int[][]PoängInsamling = int[domare][deltagare];`

**If all deltagare has the same value, all their points end up 0.**

Comment: What is the connection between `poängInsamling` and `deltagare` -- which points in the 2D array represent a single `deltagare`?

Comment: `for (int i = 0; i < deltagare; i++) {; ` See this line? You should remove that semi-colon.

Comment: @MickMnemonic View my edit. Thanks.

Comment: @wadda_wadda Do not know how that got there... However, that does not solve my problem unfortunately. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are searching the entire 2D array in order to remove the lowest and highest value across all members, but you want to remove the lowest and highest value only for the current member. You can eliminate the second loop if you keep track of the index having the maximum/minimum value.

For example, for the maximum (the minimum will be similar) :

```
    int max = -1;
    int maxIndex = -1;
    for(int i = 0; i < deltagare; i++) {
        max = -1; // clear the max value when starting with a new member
        maxIndex = -1;
        for(int t = 0; t < domare; t++) {
            if (poängInsamling[t][i] > max) {
                max = poängInsamling[t][i];
                maxIndex = t;
            }       
        }
        // clear the max value for the current member
        poängInsamling[maxIndex][i] = -1;
    }
```

Comment: Thanks! But should minimumIndex also be -1?

Comment: @Habbo It doesn't really matter what you initialize it to (since you will overwrite its value anyway). `-1` will work fine.

Comment: Check my edit. If all members get the value = 3 by 3 judges, their points should be 3 (max = 3 and min = 3), but they end up getting the value 6.

Comment: @Habbo I believe you should change `if (poängInsamling[t][i] < min)` to `if (poängInsamling[t][i] < min && poängInsamling[t][i] >= 0)`, as you had in your original code. Otherwise you will always find the minimum to be -1 (the value that was the maximum and was changed to -1).

Comment: THANKS! Cheers to you!